# Typescript cannot find name even though it is referenced

Tags: typescript

I have an angular project I'm writing in typescript. This worked well for me under VS, and now I'm trying the same with Node.JS under webstorm.

I have a progressor class, in a progressor.ts file:

```
export class Progressor{
    public tasks: any;

    constructor(){
        this.tasks = {};
    }
    ...
}
```

and I have my main controller, which uses this class:

```
/// <reference path="../progressor.ts" />

declare var angular: any; // I'm trying to eliminate these...
declare var Papa: any;
declare var $: any;

class MainController{
    constructor($scope: any){
        $scope.progressor = null;
        $scope.filesDropped = function(files, rejectedFiles){
            if(!files || !files.length)
                return;

            $scope.progressor = new Progressor();
            // ...
        }
    };
}
```

Note that this is not Node.JS code - it is simply part of a Node.JS project.

The relative reference path is correct. When I try to compile it using:

```
tsc mainController.ts --module amd --target es5
```

I get an error: Cannot find name Progressor.

I don't understand what's the problem... I've been having nothing but trouble with my Node.JS project so far, and I'm considering giving up on TS altogether for this project. First of all - can anyone tell me why it won't compile? Note that I want each TS file to be compiled separately, so I can debug them comfortably via Chrome.

Comment: Helpful : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you've `export`ed something, you need to `import` it in order to consume it, not `<reference ...` it.

Replace the `<reference` comment with `import prog = require('./progressor');`, then you can use e.g. `new prog.Progressor()`.

You might consider using `export = Progressor` so that the exported object from the other file is the class itself instead of a container.

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot! But I don't understand, why isn't the <reference path> good? What is the difference between that and 'import require'? I don't remember having to use it when I used TS under VS...

Comment: I take it back - the code now seems to have dependency for either requirejs or commonjs (I'm not sure), which is something I don't want and am pretty sure I don't have to have...

Answer (score 8):

After a while more of searching, I stumbled upon this: [TypeScript Modules](https://web.archive.org/web/20150406035504/https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Modules%20in%20TypeScript). After consulting it, I tried placing both my classes inside module{ } blocks, which solved the problem. I'm still slightly confused as to why the language would require me to use modules for multi-file usage... but for now it will do.

Comment: If you're not using requirejs or commonjs modules, you can put your classes at top-level (i.e. not inside a module) and just not put the `export` keyword on them and everything will work like you want.

Comment: Isn't this exactly the case described in the original post?

Comment: The question is contradictory/confusing about whether or not you're actually nodejs as a module loader.

Comment: The project uses node.js for server-side, but this specific example is client-side code which runs at the browser (angular)

Comment: In that case you shouldn't have top-level `export` keywords (unless you're using requirejs)